# Extract the last row of a pairs plot in R

Tags: r, ggpairs

I have created this pairs plot of a 10X10 data frame. I am interested in extracting only the last row, as it shows the covariates (on x axis) against the response parameter of interest (on y axis) for each covariate. I have used basic R pairs plot, but if a solution exist for `ggpairs` I can easily modify the code below.

```
pairs.panels(data, smooth = TRUE, scale = FALSE, density = TRUE, ellipses = FALSE)
```

The pairs plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: `pairs.panels` is not a built-in function of R. What package do you use?

Comment: @Darren Tsai -> `library(psych)`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a package called `psre` (you can install it from CRAN) and it has a function called `lsa()` (which stands for Linear Scatterplot Array).  The function does what you want.  Here's how it works:

```r
library(psre)
data(wvs)
lsa(sacsecval ~ resemaval + moral + 
                pct_univ_degree + pct_female + 
                pct_low_income, 
    xlabels = c("Emancipative Vals", "Moral Perm", 
                "% Univ Degree", "% Female", "% Low Income"), 
    ylab = "Secular Values", 
    data=wvs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the arg `horInd`, which is documented in `?graphics::pairs`.

```r
library(psych)

pairs.panels(attitude, horInd = 7)
```

[image]

The original output:

```r
pairs.panels(attitude)
```

[image]